# Capturing a URL opened by a third party program

Tags: python, url, browser, executable

I have a third party program that opens a URL in the default web browser. I want to capture that URL and pass it to a python script. What's the easiest way to do so?

At the moment I'm thinking the only way would be to create an executable which you would then set as your default browser, and that would capture the URL and pass it to the python script. However, it seems Windows 10 won't let you set your default browser to anything other than things from the Microsoft Store?

Is there a better way? I tried searching but sadly couldn't find anything other than people trying to disable the URL opening completely. I can't firewall the program as in needs internet access.

Comment: if you could assign other program instead of browser then probably you could assign directly Python script

Comment: why do you need it ? if you want to block some urls then you could add them to special file `hosts` - with IP `127.0.0.1` and then system will try to open  `127.0.0.1` . Some Antiviruses use `hosts` to block some pages.

Comment: @furas It looks like I can't assign a python script as the default browser. It's not to block URLs, but rather to parse the URLs and if they match a certain template, use that URL later in the script. It doesn't really matter if it stops the URL from actually opening or not, as the browser can be closed by the script (though not needing to would be ideal)

Comment: I don't use Windows so I don't have idea how to do it - but Chrome/Firefox keeps in database SQLite some informations - bookmarks, probalby history, and probably even urls for open tabs in browser. Python has module to read SQLite. I was reading some informations this way.